GOPRELOAD in windows to set process level environment variable?
Found the gopreload package. To what extent can this package be helpful in windows? Know that there is no such concept of preloading supported in windows. Just curious to know if I'll be able to at least set process-level environment variable for all new processes using this package though loading of .so file is obviously impossible in windows?

The gopreload is not useful on Windows at all, since it only builds on Linux.
Plugins are currently supported only on Linux, FreeBSD, and macOS.

FYI the community frowns upon answering and then voting to close the same question. The two actions are not compatible. If you think a question is off-topic then you shouldn't answer it; or if you think a question can be answered then voting to close it doesn't make much sense. If you cast a close vote and then consider the question might be on topic, you can retract your close vote.

@blackgreen Thanks for the link. You are right, I though about the questions as not very valuable to keep around, but deserving help (and an answer) nevertheless.

That sounds like a case where one could answer and downvote the question. Not all questions on SO go on to become popular and that’s fine. We only close those that are off-topic or duplicates.
